# Wpf datagrid contextmenu and SelectedCells

Tags: wpf, datagrid, contextmenu

In a WPF DataGrid I use `ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)`
when the user right clicks on a cell.

I perform an action on the `SelectedCells` of the DataGrid which supports multi-selection.

But When I select a cell A and then perform the right click on a cell B two rows higher
the context menu is shown on cell B but the action is performed on cell A.

How would you solve this problem?

Comment: That is expected. The context menu is defined on the `DataGrid`, so you can open it anywhere. As you perform actions on the `SelectedCells`, of course the action will be performed on cell `A` if that is selected. What is the behavior that you expect that solves your problem? Should only `B` be the target for the action, should it be `A` and `B`? Should the selection change to `B` when right-clicking? If you just want to position the context menu on a selected cell, which one should it be, the first in `SelectedCells`? If the target cell is not in the view, should it scroll into view?

Comment: @Gerard: Why would cell B be selected when you right-click on it?